# How to test share and rate app functionality before production in android

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps-marketplace

How can I get a link for my app to the market place while in alpha or beta? It's my first app so I want to try functionality related to the market place before releasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the format of Play Store URLs?

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin
```

Or to be more generic:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={applicationId}
```

---

Play Store URLs evolve around your applicationId, so to link to your own app you can take the base link and substitute `{applicationId}` with your `applicationId`.

If you would like to use a global constant—which is especially useful in case you have different flavors—you can use `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

> so I want to try functionality related to the market place before releasing.

Just keep in mind that you will receive error messages opening the link until your app is visible, even if you do have the correct link.

Comment: thanks Deltik. Since I'm asking them from within my app and therefore I'm sure they have google play installed I ended up using "market://details?id=com.apps.exampleapp".